# foreach-ing through a listview and accessing subitems?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, foreach

I'm having difficulty using a foreach statement with a WinForm ListView control.  The following two code blocks demonstrates what I'm trying to do.  It works with a for loop, but not a foreach.

```
foreach(var item in listView.Items){
    item. <-Can't access any of the subitems of this item
}
```

vs

```
for(int i=0;i<listView.Items.Count;i++){
    listView.Items[i].Subitems[1] <- Here I can access the sub items
}
```

I'm trying to use a foreach loop so I can more easily remove items from the ListView.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to specify the type:

```
foreach(ListViewItem item in listView.Items){
```

To answer your comments:

This is because most controls' item collections implement the non-generic `ICollection` (and `IEnumerable`), see [this MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.aspx) for `ListViewItemCollection` for example. Since it doesn't implement the generic `ICollection<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`, the compiler can't guess the type of the items from looking at the collections themselves, so you have to tell it that they're of type `ListViewItem` instead of using `var`.

Comment: Why is it that var won't suffice in this situation?

Comment: What other situations is var not sufficient?

Comment: The Items collection type is Object. That's why inference do the variable behind var as Object too. The listview Items can either be a collection of ListViewItem if you add them manually, or a collection of your own objects if you uses DataSource.

Comment: @BoltClock wouldn't it be better to use `forearch(ListViewDataItem item in listView.Items){`? By being a specific type is would be more efficient, right?

Comment: @DanielV: That's ASP.NET ListView. This is WinForms ListView, whose Items property is a non-generic collection of ListViewItems (there is no ListViewDataItem in WinForms).

Comment: @BoltClock you are completely correct, my bad, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the type if the item in the collection explicitly. The `var` keyword uses type inference in order to determine the type of the variable. In the case of `var` in a `foreach` clause, it uses the particular implementation of `IEnumerable` to determine the type.

- If the collection only implements `IEnumerable` (and not a generic `IEnumerable<T>`), then `var` will be `object`
- If the collection implements one generic `IEnumerable<T>` (say, `IEnumerable<int>`), then `var` will be `T` (in the example here, `var` would be `int`)

In your case, `ListViewItemCollection` does not implement any generic form of `IEnumerable<T>`, so `var` is assumed to be `object`. However, the compiler will allow you to specify a more specific type for the iterator variable if the enumerable only implements `IEnumerable`, and it automatically inserts a cast to that particular type.

Note that, because there's a casting operator, the cast will fail at runtime if the object is not of that particular type. For instance, I can do this:

```
List<object> foo = new List<object>();

foo.Add("bar");
foo.Add(1);

foreach(string bar in foo)
{

}
```

This is legal, but will fail when the iterator reaches the second item, since it is not a `string`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the type of the item - in this case: `ListViewItem`.

Also, if you're planning to remove items from the collection and are using a foreach loop, you cannot directly remove from the you're looping through - you'd need to add each item to remove to a new collection and remove all items in that collection from the original after the termination of the loop.

Comment: I might go back to using a for and iterating backwards.  Thanks for this information.

Answer (score 0):

Use the beautiful collection caster of LINQ

```
using System.Linq;

foreach(var item in listView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()){
    item.BackColor = ...
}
```

Comment: BoltClock's answer seems cleaner. Which method is preferred, or more industry standard?

Comment: @sooprise: Use @BoltClock's version; `Cast<T>()` is useful for query composition, but is just a bit of unnecessary overhead and verbosity here.

Comment: Yeah, while LINQ *can* do this, it's probably not intended to.